# python file renaming using os module

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the script

```
import os
x = os.listdir("/media/virus/Data/Songs/Taylor swift/Taylor Swift - 1989 (Deluxe Version)")
for i in x:
    print i 
    os.rename(i,i[20:])
```

the error was shown as follows

```
virus@ShashwatVirus ~ $ python plsdelete.py 
01 - Taylor Swift - Welcome To New York.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plsdelete.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.rename(i,i[20:])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The os module is listing the files correctly
But the problem arises when I try to rename
I also checked in /usr/lib/python 2.7

Comment: Can you remove or rename this file without sudo rights?

Answer (score 1):

[`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns the filenames inside the given folder, but not their complete paths. `os.rename` doesn't know that you think you're looking at files inside that particular folder. You're just giving it filenames with no context.

You can construct the paths to those filenames using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os#os.path.join) to join the folder path to the filename.

```
folder = "/media/virus/Data/Songs/Taylor swift/Taylor Swift - 1989 (Deluxe Version)"
filenames = os.listdir(folder)
for filename in filenames:
    oldpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    newpath = os.path.join(folder, filename[20:])
    os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the filenames passed to `rename`:

```
import os
my_dir = "/media/virus/Data/Songs/Taylor swift/Taylor Swift - 1989 (Deluxe Version)"
x = os.listdir(my_dir)
for i in x:
    print i 
    os.rename(os.path.join(my_dir, i), os.path.join(my_dir, i[20:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

I just changed the working directory by adding

`os.chdir("/media/virus/Data/Songs/Taylor swift/Taylor Swift - 1989 (Deluxe Version)")`